# Uniformly sample $x,y\in\{0,1\}^n$ with Levenstein distance $k$

Tags: sampling, edit-distance, monte-carlo

Given alphabet $\{0,1\}$, we want to uniformly sample $x,y \in \{0,1\}^n$ such that $ed(x,y)=k$, where $ed$ denotes the [Levenstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), i.e., the minimum number of edit operations (insert, delete, substitute) that can transform $x$ to $y$.

Clearly, this can be done by brute force over all pairs of strings, which is very costly. To reduce the complexity, my main idea is to use Monte Carlo sampling:

*Monte Carlo sampling:* pick $x\sim\{0,1\}^n$ at random, introduce $k$ successive edit operations (equal number of delete and insert to end up with the same length) ending up in string $y$ and reject the pair iff $ed(x,y)\neq k$. The main challenge is to guarantee that the probability of confirmation is not exponentially low. Such a low probability of success forces us to repeat the sampling an exponential number of times, rendering any time savings useless.

*Informal analysis:* Let $x=:x_0\to \dots \to x_k:=y$ denote the intermediary strings during our $k$ random edits.  Let $S_i(x)$ for $i\le n$ denote the level set for edit distance from $x$:
$$S_i(x)=\{y\in \{0,1\}^n: ed(x,y)=i\}.$$
Therefore, $ed(x,y)=k$ implies $x_i\in S_i$ for all $i=0,\dots, k$.
By construction, if we have $x_i\in S_i$, then $x_{i+1}$ must belong to one of $S_{i-1}, S_i, S_{i+1}$ level sets. Therefore, the probability of failure at step $i$ is bounded by the ratio $\alpha_i=(|S_i|+|S_{i-1}|)/(|S_i|+|S_{i-1}|+|S_{i+1}|)$. It remains to show that if $k$ is small (how small?) the ratio $\alpha_i$ remains very high, and in fact $\prod_i^k \alpha_i$ is not exponentially low.

Two main questions:

- How can we make my hand-wavy argument more rigorous?
- In the regime that $k$ is comparable to $n$ the proposed algorithm provably fails. Namely if $k>2n/3$, random walks will never get you much further than $ed(x,y)\approx n/2$, as even the edit distance of two randomly generated strings is concentrated around $n/2$. What would be an alternative to sampling for large $k$?

Comment: Are you working in a regime where $k \ll n$?  Where $k$ is large and close to $n$?  Do you know?

Comment: Thank you for raising this question, I added some explanation to the post. While both cases are relevant, I think the case of large $k$ is more challenging.

Comment: It's not the case that $x_i \in S_i \implies x_{i+1} \in S_i \cup S_{i+1}$, since it could be that the $(i+1)$-th edit undoes the $i$-th. In such cases, $x_{i+1} \in S_{i-1}$.

Comment: But note that an edit can never take you backwards further than 1 step, since that would contradict the optimality of the length-$i$ edit scripts in $S_i$: If $x_{i+1} \in S_{i-2}$, then you could transform $x_i$ into $y$ by first making 1 edit to get $x_{i+1}$, then $i-2$ edits to get $y$, for a total of $i-1$ edits.

Comment: you're right, I corrected the statement in the post, thank you! @j_random_hacker

Answer (score 3):

There are two considerations: running time, and correctness.

Running time: When $k < (n-1)/\lg(4n)$, heuristically I expect the running time of your algorithm to be fine and I'd guess you won't experience exponential blowup.  We can show $|S_k| \le (4n)^k$, so when $k < (n-1)/\lg(4n)$, $|S_k|/2^n \le 1/2$.  This is not a proof; to prove that everything is OK, we need to prove that $|S_k|/(|S_0| + \dots + |S_k|)$ is not too small, and I don't have a proof of that.

For large $k$, I don't know what algorithm might be suitable.

Correctness: Your method is not correct.  It does not produce $(x,y)$ with the right distribution.  Given $x$, not all $y \in S_k(x)$ will be equally be likely to be reached by the procedure you give, so your approach introduces a bias in the distribution of $x,y$.

For example, suppose $x=10001$ and $k=2$.  If $y=00000$, there is just one edit script that transforms $x$ into $y$ (substitute bits 1 and 5).  If $y=10010$, there are seven edit scripts that transform $x$ into $y$ (substitute bits 4 and 5; or, delete one of bits 2-4 and insert a 0 at the end, or do the same in the opposite order).  So, if $x=10001$, your algorithm will be seven times as likely to output $(10001,10010)$ as it is to output $(10001,00000)$.  This deviates from the uniform distribution.

Incidentally, I believe the procedure you outline is just rejection sampling (i.e., just Monte Carlo), not MCMC.

Comment: Interesting point. However, I don't fully agree with your conclusion about the correctness. Uniform sampling of all pairs $x,y$ with $ed(x,y)=k$ also has an intrinsic bias to some strings. In other words, if we take the first string out of the uniformly sampled *pair*, it is not a uniformly random string.

Comment: @AmeerJewdaki,  Well, look, you specified that distribution as what you wanted, so we can only answer based on the requirements in the question.